# iOS - How to build a subview with "Passcode Lock" look - like in a settings.bundle

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I would like to have a subview in settings.bundle which works like the Passcode Lock section in settings -> general.

More specifically, I would like to have a subview with the functionality that I can change an access key used in my app, asking for the old one to change for a new one.

Some one have some code, clue, tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the apple documentation? It explains how to do this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Or check this tutorial http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846575&seqNum=12

If you are wanting to make it look JUST LIKE the passcode lock screen it will be hard to do. Apple limits what a developer can do to the settings menu for their application. You could just put 4 text boxes on the screen but it won't be able to automatically go to the next box since you cannot add code to your settings bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bot,
The thing is I would like the functionality where you ask for the old code to set a new one, no really matters the look and feel. It appears the problem starts in the point where I would make the calculation (compare stored code with old code to proceed to change for the new one), because there is no place to make that calculation (a view controller) as you said. So, it appears it is definitely not possible, right?